# How to use TWIG bootstrap template block in a Symfony2 form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I don't undestand how to use blocks defined in bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig to custumize my form.

So far I did this and it's working fine.

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
<div class="well">
    {{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.title, {'label': 'Titre'}) }}

    {{ form_row(form.content, {'label': "Content"}) }}

 ...

    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

But If I try to use. or any other block defined in bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout like

```
{{ textarea_widget(form.content, {'label': "Content"}) }}
```

It's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that you're calling in the first example (`form_start`, `form_errors` etc.) are functions defined in a Twig extension ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#form)) that *use* the defined theme to generate output. So the blocks defined within `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig` are called by those functions (which are an extension of the Symfony form view component), you can't directly "call" those blocks yourself.

If you're trying to customise the output of your form, the easiest way to do it is to create your own form theme that extends from the base theme:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block textarea_widget %}
    {# your code #}
{% endblock %}
```

This is described in the [Symfony cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

If you're trying to call a widget directly, you're better changing the type of your form field that is passed to the renderer. The different types available are in the [form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#built-in-field-types). The type you choose defines which block will be rendered from your theme - so in your case if you change the field type to `textarea`, the `textarea_widget` (well, `textarea_row` first) will be rendered. If you need an overview of this, the [form fragment naming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-template-blocks) docs should help you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to John Noel I find the answer.
To summarize if someone is looking to do the same thing.

To use bootstrap3 predifined layout in your Symfony2 forms

1 - Declare the form theme to use.

in your twig template

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
```

Or globally for all your forms in /app/config/config.yml

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    form:
        #resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
```

2 - Use the [Symfony Twig Extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#form) to display your form

- form
- form_start
- form_end
- form_enctype
- form_widget
- form_errors
- form_label
- form_row
- form_rest

3 - You must use the correct [Form Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html) within your formbuilder (this is the part I was missing).

Ex : to use Bootstrap 3 widget money.

In your form.html.twig

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}

  {{ form_start(form) }}

...

    {{ form_row(form.price, {'label': "Price"}) }}

...

    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

In your FormType

```
$builder->add('price', 'money');
```

I hope this can help someone as this is what I wish I have found !
Thanks again to John Noel